# Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement'

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to write a query using a prepared statement.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO notification(MessageId,TopicArn,Subject,Message,Timestamp,SignatureVersion,Signature,SigningCertURL,UnsubscribeURL,topicid) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

This throws the following exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement'
```

Where as the following query works

```
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO notification(MessageId,TopicArn,Subject,Message,Timestamp,SignatureVersion,Signature,SigningCertURL,UnsubscribeURL,topicid) 
        VALUES (".$message['MessageId'].", '".$message['TopicArn']."', '".$message['Subject']."', '".$message['Message']."', '".$message['Timestamp']."',".$message['SignatureVersion'].", '".$message['Signature']."', '".$message['SigningCertURL']."', '".$message['UnsubscribeURL']."', ".$topic.")");
```

I want to use prepared statement with bind_param() function. What is wrong with first query? Please help.

Comment: you need to use `$stmt->bind_param('is',$intvar,$strvar)` etc before executing the statement. The latter example works perhaps but is incorrect and opens your code to sql injection possibilities

Comment: @RamRaider     $conn->prepare is returning false. So can't use $query->bind_param()

Comment: where is your bind_param for the first query?

Comment: @RamRaider     Both the queries are the same only difference is instead of '?' I have used value.

Comment: Why  you are not binding the data?

Comment: @PranavMS      Please see above comments. Prepare is failing and returning boolean false. So can't use bind_param() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested - you need to bind parameters to values before you can execute the sql ~ like this perhaps:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$sql='insert into notification
    (messageid,topicarn,subject,message,timestamp,signatureversion,signature,signingcerturl,unsubscribeurl,topicid) 
    values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $conn->prepare( sql );
if( $stmt ){
    /* assumed mainly strings other than those with `id` in column name */
    $stmt->bind_param('issssssssi',
        $message['MessageId'],
        $message['TopicArn'],
        $message['Subject'],
        $message['Message'],
        $message['Timestamp'],
        $message['SignatureVersion'],
        $message['Signature'],
        $message['SigningCertURL'],
        $message['UnsubscribeURL'],
        $topic
    );
    $result=$stmt->execute();

    /* Other code */

} else {
    /* investigate why "prepare" method failed */
    echo "Error:";
}
```

Comment: $stmt is false so it will not go inside if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the data like below.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){ 
    $stmt->bind_param('issssssssi', $message['MessageId'], $message['TopicArn'],
        $message['Subject'], $message['Message'], $message['Timestamp'],
        $message['SignatureVersion'], $message['Signature'],   $message['SigningCertURL'],
        $message['UnsubscribeURL'] ,$message['UnsubscribeURL']  );
}
```

You just forgot to add `$` infront of the `sql` please add that and try again.

Comment: Please check the other comments. $stmt is false.

Comment: I am not using $sql. Please see my question.